# How to read whole email inbox programmatically and show in table view

Tags: iphone, email, ios4

I want to read a whole inbox from a Gmail account and show in a `tableView` cell. Please help me.

Comment: StackOverflow is **not** a site where you can come to just ask `give teh codez plz`.  This is a broad question.  Please come with a specific problem and everyone will be willing to help you.

Comment: Make your question more concise or split it into multiple questions if you need help on multiple subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pantomime](http://www.collaboration-world.com/cgi-bin/project/index.cgi?pid=3) is an Objective C IMAP library, but I don't know if the license is compatible with iOS apps. But based on the phrasing in your question, you might want to start with a smaller project if you're just starting out.

Try looking at the sample code projects on the [Apple Developer Connection](http://developer.apple.com/ios) site, and then come back with more specific questions when you run into difficulties.

Comment: sorry sir , i am new in iphone so that my question asking way is wrong.

Comment: @sudo rm -rf, @steven Kramer , @ alex reynolds ,@ Pablo santa Cruz : sorry sir , i am new in iphone so that my question asking way is wrong. please give me a permission to asking question . i promise that from next question i ask the specific problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need an IMAP library to connect to GMAIL and read messages.